# Prove that if $h_{1},h_{2} \in H$ and $k_{1},k_{2} \in K$ and $h_{1}k_{1}=h_{2}k_{2}$ , then $h_{1}=h_{2}$ and $k_{1}=k_{2}$

Tags: group-theory

> Suppose $G$ is a group with identity element $1$, that $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$, and that $H\cap K=\{1\}$. Prove that if $h_{1},h_{2} \in H$, $k_{1},k_{2} \in K$ and $h_{1}k_{1}=h_{2}k_{2}$, then $h_{1}=h_{2}$ and $k_{1}=k_{2}$.

My attempt:

$h_{1}k_{1}=h_{2}k_{2}$ then $k_{1}=h_{1}^{-1}h_{2}k_{2}$
so $h_{1}^{-1}h_{2}=1$ and $k_{1}=k_{2}$, because $H\cap K=\{1\}$.

Any tips, hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you did not use the hypothesis correctly. $h_2^{-1}h_1=k_2k_1^{-1}$ so each side is in $H \cap K=\{1\}$ which gives $h_2=h_1$ and $k_2=k_1$

Comment: Im trying to say that since $h_{1}^{-1}h_{2}$ is in H so it can't be in K unless they are both equal to the identity so the product must equal to 1 is that wrong?

Comment: @Rivaldo I know you have the right idea but you did not express it correctly.